# Virtualenv is attempting to install in system directory

Tags: python, macos, virtualenv

I ran into a problem earlier, trying to install gevent in my virtualenv.  I tried a few different things, including a few export commands, installing XCode command line tools, installing the GCC compiler... none of which worked.

In the process, I managed to screw up my virtualenv install.  I have removed the virtualenv directory and am attempting to recreate it, with no luck.  I've uninstalled and reinstalled virtualenv (using pip) and I am still getting the following error after running the following command.

Command:

```
virtualenv ENV
```

I'd like to know why it is looking in the /Library for the installation directory.  Is there  a setting somewhere to fix that?

**UPDATE**
v2: removed virtual burrito

Ouput with --verbose:

```
Creating ENV/lib/python2.7
Symlinking Python bootstrap modules
Symlinking ENV/lib/python2.7/config
Symlinking ENV/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
Symlinking ENV/lib/python2.7/os.py
Ignoring built-in bootstrap module: posix
Symlinking ENV/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py
Cannot import bootstrap module: nt
Symlinking ENV/lib/python2.7/ntpath.py
Symlinking ENV/lib/python2.7/genericpath.py
Symlinking ENV/lib/python2.7/fnmatch.py
Symlinking ENV/lib/python2.7/locale.py
Symlinking ENV/lib/python2.7/encodings
Symlinking ENV/lib/python2.7/codecs.py
Symlinking ENV/lib/python2.7/stat.py
Symlinking ENV/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py
Symlinking ENV/lib/python2.7/copy_reg.py
Symlinking ENV/lib/python2.7/types.py
Symlinking ENV/lib/python2.7/re.py
Symlinking ENV/lib/python2.7/sre.py
Symlinking ENV/lib/python2.7/sre_parse.py
Symlinking ENV/lib/python2.7/sre_constants.py
Symlinking ENV/lib/python2.7/sre_compile.py
Symlinking ENV/lib/python2.7/warnings.py
Symlinking ENV/lib/python2.7/linecache.py
Symlinking ENV/lib/python2.7/_abcoll.py
Symlinking ENV/lib/python2.7/abc.py
Symlinking ENV/lib/python2.7/_weakrefset.py
Creating ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Writing ENV/lib/python2.7/site.py
Writing ENV/lib/python2.7/orig-prefix.txt
Writing ENV/lib/python2.7/no-global-site-packages.txt
Creating parent directories for ENV/include
Symlinking ENV/include/python2.7
Creating ENV/bin
New python executable in ENV/bin/python
Changed mode of ENV/bin/python to 0755
Symlinking ENV/.Python
Testing executable with ENV/bin/python -c "import sys;out=sys.stdout;getattr(out, "buffer", out).write(sys.prefix.encode("utf-8"))"
Got sys.prefix result: u'/Users/aharwood/Documents/SUCode/mds-item-read-svc/ENV'
Creating ENV/lib/python2.7/distutils
Writing ENV/lib/python2.7/distutils/__init__.py
Writing ENV/lib/python2.7/distutils/distutils.cfg
Using existing setuptools egg: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.9.1-py2.7.egg/virtualenv_support/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg
Installing setuptools...
error: can't create or remove files in install directory
The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:
  [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/test-easy-install-3535.write-test'
The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:
  /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/
Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  If the
installation directory is a system-owned directory, you may need to sign in
as the administrator or "root" account.  If you do not have administrative
access to this machine, you may wish to choose a different installation
directory, preferably one that is listed in your PYTHONPATH environment
variable.
For information on other options, you may wish to consult the
documentation at:
  http://peak.telecommunity.com/EasyInstall.html
Please make the appropriate changes for your system and try again.
Complete output from command /Users/aharwood/Docu...d-svc/ENV/bin/python -c "#!python
\"\"\"Bootstra...sys.argv[1:])






" /Library/Python/2.7/...ols-0.6c11-py2.7.egg:
error: can't create or remove files in install directory

The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/test-easy-install-3535.write-test'

The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/

Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  If the
installation directory is a system-owned directory, you may need to sign in
as the administrator or "root" account.  If you do not have administrative
access to this machine, you may wish to choose a different installation
directory, preferably one that is listed in your PYTHONPATH environment
variable.

For information on other options, you may wish to consult the
documentation at:

http://peak.telecommunity.com/EasyInstall.html

Please make the appropriate changes for your system and try again.

----------------------------------------
...Installing setuptools...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 8, in <module>
load_entry_point('virtualenv==1.9.1', 'console_scripts', 'virtualenv')()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.9.1-py2.7.egg/virtualenv.py", line 979, in main
no_pip=options.no_pip)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.9.1-py2.7.egg/virtualenv.py", line 1091, in create_environment
search_dirs=search_dirs, never_download=never_download)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.9.1-py2.7.egg/virtualenv.py", line 611, in install_setuptools
search_dirs=search_dirs, never_download=never_download)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.9.1-py2.7.egg/virtualenv.py", line 583, in _install_req
cwd=cwd)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.9.1-py2.7.egg/virtualenv.py", line 1057, in call_subprocess
% (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /Users/aharwood/Docu...d-svc/ENV/bin/python -c "#!python
\"\"\"Bootstra...sys.argv[1:])






" /Library/Python/2.7/...ols-0.6c11-py2.7.egg failed with error code 1
```

**UPDATE** v3: I found one of the things I did to try to install gevent.  Would this cause my problem?

```
sudo port install libevent
CFLAGS="-I /opt/local/include -L /opt/local/lib" pip install gevent
```

Comment: I think your `virtualenv` is still hosed: instead of trying to install setuptools in the env, it's being installed systemwide (which fails because of insufficient permissions). Try running `virtualenv --verbose ENV` to see if there's anything in the log that might give a clue.

Answer (score 0):

This line looks suspicious:

```
Using existing setuptools egg: /Users/aharwood/.venvburrito/lib/python/virtualenv-1.9.1-py2.7.egg/virtualenv_support/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg
```

Are you actively using [virtualenv-burrito](https://github.com/brainsik/virtualenv-burrito)? I'm not sure exactly what it does, but [looking at the install file](https://raw.github.com/brainsik/virtualenv-burrito/master/virtualenv-burrito.sh) it changes your shell's startup commands, which may be causing your problems.

I would try and move it out of the way, open a new Terminal window, and see if running virtualenv works properly again:

```
mv ~/.venvburrito ~/.venvburrito.disabled
```

If that solves your problem, you could remove it more permanently:

```
rm -fr ~/.venvburrito.disabled
```

It also installs some code in one of these files (depending on your shell):

```
~/.bash_profile
~/.zprofile
~/.profile
```

You could remove that code, but it looks like it won't cause any problems if you leave it in.

Comment: Good call.  I actually installed virtualburrito after I started having this problem, hoping that it would supersede the issues I'm having.  I will remove it in the hopes that might do something for me.

Comment: I removed virtual burrito but am still getting the same error.  New output is above.